# Cover letter for a dependent family for a UK Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I've applied for a successful UK visit visa before through a travel agent. I had my wife and 2 sons as my dependents. Hence, my travel agent wrote a comprehensive letter under the title "Section 9" on about 3 pages, providing the details of the complete trip, purpose of the visit and my detailed assets/bank details. He, then added a government issued "Stamp Paper" signed by me as an undertaking to support the dependent family for entire duration of the trip.

That was my first ever VISA for UK. I'm now planing to re-apply. Would a simple and precise cover letter be sufficient or should I follow the same practice?

Comment: You mean whether to pay an agent or apply by yourself?! That's a judgement call you have to make and should be closed as opinion based. Maybe you could rephrase to ask more about associated risks / advantages to make the question more suitable.

Comment: @mts I mean re-apply! Obviously I do not want to go to an agent, who would repeat the same process. Hence I'm asking here for an opinion.

Comment: It's actually not clear, but this visa application was refused, correct? You will need to post the refusal notice with the personal details blacked out. Then perhaps the question can be reopened or links to other Q&As given.

Comment: @mkennedy No. The visa was successful. And I visited the UK. But now I'm planning to reapply myself without an agent as the previous visa has expired.